# UBUNTU Desktop Management Tool

Tags: automation

I am looking for a Desktop Management GUI Tool to control and manage ubuntu laptops or desktops where it supports Inventory,RemoteExecution,log audit,provisioning,remote desktop or console,Monitoring systems,Application Management,patch management,Repository Management and Configuration Management. Please suggest accordingly.

Comment: Cross-posted here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/61756/ubuntu-desktop-management-tool.

Answer (score 0):

The only application that comes to mind is *GSConnect*

```
sudo apt install gsconnect
```

It does everything you just described but from your phone, via the *KDE Connect* app

Comment: Thanks, but i need to access GUI from Computer.